# Find the coefficients of the Fourier series that minimise the error.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

I am having a little trouble understanding what I have to actually do here. What does differentiate with respect to bn? I thinks after differentiation I must use some calculus theorem about extreme but how do I get there?

Comment: It is basically the same thing as in linear regression except that the sum is transformed to an integral because the infinity of points. And you want that $E_N$ be minimum; so, you write that the derivatives are all zero. I know this is very simplistic as an answer but it could help you understanding. If this is not the case, just post.

Comment: Could you be e little more specific please?

Comment: You want that $E_N$ be minimum. To achieve that, you need that $\frac{dE_N}{db_k}=0$ for each $k$ from $1$ to $N$. From there, you get the $b_k$'s solving a set of equations. If you have an example, we can try. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1,…,v_n$ are orthogonal vectors wrt. some scalar product and its norm, then
$$
\|y-(c_1v_1+…+c_nv_n)\|
$$
gets minimized by the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the subspace spanned by $v_1,…v_n$. Which means that the coefficients are obtained as
$$
c_k=\frac{\langle y,v_k\rangle}{\|v_k\|^2}
$$

Comment: In this case, you have the scalar product $<f,g> = \int_{-\pi}^\pi fg$ and $y=f(x)$ and $c_i = b_i$ and $v_i = \sin i x$.